# jQuery call function with each item in selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call a function using each object found in jQuery selection

```
<a href="#" class="can-click" data-code="a">a</a>
<a href="#" class="can-click" data-code="b">b</a>
<a href="#" class="can-click" data-code="c">c</a>
<a href="#" class="can-click" data-code="d">d</a>
```

Each `a` element has a data-code value:

```
<p class="output" data-value="1"></p>
<p class="output" data-value="2"></p>
<p class="output" data-value="3"></p>
```

Each `p` element has a data-value:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".can-click").click(function () {
    var code = $(this).data("code");
        $("output").each(Display(code));
    });
});
```

What I want is that when you click on the anchor `a` you will get an alert showing you the data-code from the anchor clicked and the data-value for each `p`, with the code attached I want 3 alerts to pop up.

```
function Display(code) {

    var p = $(this);
    var value = p.data("value");
        alert(code + " " + value);
}
```

Here is a link to the code in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mikeu/XFd4n/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use `.` for class-selectors and pass `this` object when you are calling `Display` function like,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".can-click").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var code = $(this).data("code");
    $(".output").each(function() { // use . for class selectors
      Display(code, this); // pass this from here
    });
  });
});

function Display(code, ths) { // ths = this, current output element
  var p = $(ths), // use ths instead of this
    value = p.data("value");
  console.log(code + " " + value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="can-click" data-code="a">a</a>
<a href="#" class="can-click" data-code="b">b</a>
<a href="#" class="can-click" data-code="c">c</a>
<a href="#" class="can-click" data-code="d">d</a>
<p class="output" data-value="1"></p>
<p class="output" data-value="2"></p>
<p class="output" data-value="3"></p>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:-

You need to pass in function reference to the obj.each callback. `obj.each(Display(code))` is wrong, it should be `obj.each(Display)` ; but since here you want to pass in the variable, you can invoke it inside an anonymous function.

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vn8PE/)

```
 $(".output").each(function(){ 
                Display(code, this)});
        });
```

#### Script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".can-click").click(function () {
        var code = $(this).data("code");
        $(".output").each(function(){ 
            Display(code, this)});
    });
});


function Display(code,$this) {

    var p = $($this);
    var value = p.data("value");
    alert(code + " " + value);
}
```